# Find max value in each cell across multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I am trying to obtain the max value for each cell across three different dataset. As a toy example, imagine these three data frames:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
b <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
c <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
 
> a
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 15  2 15  2 15
2 19  6 19  6 19
3 14 11 14 11 14
4  3  5  3  5  3
5 10  4 10  4 10
> b
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 14 10 14 10 14
2  5  7  5  7  5
3  9 15  9 15  9
4  3 18  3 18  3
5  8 17  8 17  8
> c
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  4  5  4  5  4
2 14 12 14 12 14
3 17 10 17 10 17
4 11 16 11 16 11
5  7  9  7  9  7
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe of the same dimensions, where each cell has the maximum value across `a`, `b` and `c`. For example, cell `[1,1]` of the new dataframe should have the value `15` (from df `a`). I managed to do this by looping across columns, and getting the maximum value, but it was rather slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pmax` :

```
pmax(a, b, c)
#OR
Reduce(pmax, list(a, b, c))

#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1 15 10 15 10 15
#2 19 12 19 12 19
#3 17 15 17 15 17
#4 11 18 11 18 11
#5 10 17 10 17 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options but not as concise as `pmax` by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060364/12158757)

- `rowMaxs` wit `Map`

```
> library(matrixStats)

> list2DF(Map(function(...) rowMaxs(cbind(...)),a,b,c))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 15 10 15 10 15
2 19 12 19 12 19
3 17 15 17 15 17
4 11 18 11 18 11
5 10 17 10 17 10
```

- `array`

```
> lst <- list(a,b,c)

> data.frame(apply(array(unlist(lst),c(dim(lst[[1]]),length(lst))),1:2,max))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 15 10 15 10 15
2 19 12 19 12 19
3 17 15 17 15 17
4 11 18 11 18 11
5 10 17 10 17 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `do.call`

```
do.call(pmax, list(a, b, c))
```